# Graphics - Determining the Radius of TRIANGLE_FAN Circle and Local Coordinates from World Coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, linear-algebra

At the moment, I have a solar system in openGL with multiple coordinate systems. I.e., the sun has its own orbit coordinate system for planets that orbit around it and its own coordinate system for the circle that represents the sun. Every planet has its own orbitCS and CS for its shape.

I use GL_TRIANGLE_FAN to make spheres for the planets.

Then, when I receive mouse coordinates, I use glUnProject to translate them from window to world coordinates. Then, I attempt to translate these world coordinates to local coordinates to determine if a mouse click is within a planet shape or not. If so, it outputs the name of the planet - the hard part is getting the planet click recognition to work.

I can not seem to figure out how to do this properly. The formula I am using true if ((pow(target_LCS[0],2) + pow(target_LCS[1],2)) < pow(radius,2)) does not seem to work correctly. Instead of determining whether or not the click is in the shape, it is never true. I also do not know how to properly determine the radius with the TRIANGLE_FAN.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL knows nothing about objects. When you create a sphere with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` you must have code that tells opengl where to draw the sphere and what the radius is. If you want to do intersection testing, you will need to keep track of the planet radii and the planet positions  *yourself*. So just use the positions and radii specified from the drawing code.